# How to use preCachePicture() in flutter_svg

Tags: flutter, svg, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I'm using [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) package to render SVG images in my app, as flutter does not officially supports SVG yet.I'm having a delay of probably few seconds while trying to load SVG images in my app and while looking for the solution I found out that I can preload the SVG image using [preCachePicture()](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_svg/latest/svg/precachePicture.html). The problem is that the official [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) documentation does not clearly states nor there are other web material to show how to use this function to preload SVG images.

I'm calling `loadPictures()` function in `initState()` to preload the SVG picture.

```
String onboardImage = 'assets/images/onboard.svg';

@override
  void initState() {
    loadPictures();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> loadPictures() async {
    await precachePicture(ExactAssetPicture((SvgPicture.svgStringDecoder),onboardImage), null);    
  }
```

> After calling `preCachePicture()`, How to load the precached image
>   when I wanted to use it ?

Comment: the docs say: *"If the image is later used by an SvgPicture, it will probably be loaded faster. The consumer of the image does not need to use the same PictureProvider instance. The PictureCache will find the picture as long as both pictures share the same key."*

Comment: @pskink I see but can you explain the docs?

Comment: @pskink Can you answer where to put the keys? As SvgPicture takes a key as an argument but preCachePicture doesn't seems to take key in constructer.

Comment: you need to use the same `PictureProvider` - both in `preCachePicture` and `SvgPicture`

Answer (score 29):

To cache multiple SVGs, do this:

```dart
Future.wait([
  precachePicture(
    ExactAssetPicture(
      SvgPicture.svgStringDecoder, // See UPDATE below!
      'assets/my_icon.svg',
    ),
    null,
  ),
  precachePicture(
    ExactAssetPicture(
      SvgPicture.svgStringDecoder, // See UPDATE below!
      'assets/my_asset.svg',
    ),
    null,
  ),
  // other SVGs or images here
]);
```

Note: do this in `main.dart`, or in a widget which is displayed **before** the widget which uses the SVG. For example, you can do it on splash screen if you need an svg for login or signup.

---

**UPDATE**: as per [riccardogabellone's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62257156/how-to-use-precachepicture-in-flutter-svg/64283037?noredirect=1#comment124100423_64283037), since late 2021, instead of `SvgPicture.svgStringDecoder` we should use `SvgPicture.svgStringDecoderOutsideViewBoxBuilder` or `SvgPicture.svgStringDecoderBuilder`.

Comment: from last package updates: instead of SvgPicture.svgStringDecoder, should be used SvgPicture.svgStringDecoderOutsideViewBoxBuilder or SvgPicture.svgStringDecoderBuilder

Comment: @riccardogabellone thanks, I won't update the answer but I hope Your comment will help others :)

Comment: @Aleksandar You should. Comments are less visible, you could edit your answer and add "Edit as 2021: use ......"

Comment: Am i wrong or `precachePicture` isn't working in Flutter 3.7?

Comment: @faccio not sure really. Haven't used it for some time now.

Answer (score 15):

**2023 UPDATE:** *flutter_svg 2.0.0+1*

You could have noticed that `precachePicture` has been deprecated. hygehyge has come up with a new [working solution](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/841#issuecomment-1416160435):

```dart
const loader = SvgAssetLoader('res/large_icon.svg');
svg.cache.putIfAbsent(loader.cacheKey(null), () => loader.loadBytes(null));
```

Comment: where do you get the "svg.cache" from ?

Comment: This is the best and current solution

Comment: @Jerbs from flutter_svg package.

Comment: How do you call the image afterwards?

Comment: @faccio do you really need to run the whole `putIfAbsent`, since it already runs inside of `loadBytes`, seems like this is doing the same thing twice?

Comment: same with @Giraldi how could we find and use those cached images?

Answer (score 8):

Calling precache in your widget's initState is too late. You should instead call this method in the main() function like this:

```
Future<void> main() async {
    await precachePicture(ExactAssetPicture(SvgPicture.svgStringDecoder, 'assets/images/onboard.svg'), null);
    runApp(YourApp());
}
```

Comment: What if I had to cache multiple svg?

Comment: @Shubhamhackz check my answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

adding to the answer @faccio has already provided, we can also create a precache function.. the Future.wait ensures you can cache multiple items

***main.dart***

```
void main() async {
  await precacheInitialAssets();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

precacheInitialAssets() async {
  await Future.wait([
  precacheSvgPicture('assets/svg/logo.svg'),
]);
}
```

***helpers.dart***

```
Future precacheSvgPicture(String svgPath) async {
  final logo = SvgAssetLoader(svgPath);
  await svg.cache.putIfAbsent(logo.cacheKey(null), () => logo.loadBytes(null));
}
```

but i would not advice precaching all your assets on the main.dart, just the initial once, then some others in the initstate of your splash screen